# Nea login part loop?

Tags: python, loops

im on the first part of my course work and im cleaning it up

i want to keep copying and pasting but i know looping it is time efficient and infinite

```
username = ["bob", "kye", "mes", "omar", "luke", "ben", "robin", "sam"]
name=str(input("whats  name 1 "))
round=0

if name in username:
    print(" p1 Authenticated")
    name2=str(input("whats name 2 "))
    if name2 in username:
        print(" *STARTING GAME* ")
    else:
        print("Invalid User")

else:
    print("Invalid User")
```

if you type and name not previously made it should loop like try again till a valid name is typed up

but if i type something wrong code continues and stops when they needs the name

Comment: Read up on `while`-loops. Consider providing an exit condition or timeout condition if its too inefficient.

Comment: There is no loop in your code. Try with `while` loop. Also you need not to cast the input to `str` as it is already `str`

Comment: [looping techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code would ask for the name as many times needed until the user inserts the valid name.

```py
name_one = ''
name_two = ''
usernames = ['bob', 'kye', 'mes', 'omar']

while name_one not in usernames:
    name_one = input('Insert first name: ')

while name_two not in usernames:
    name_two = input('Insert first name: ')
```

Another way would be:

```py
names = []
usernames = ['bob', 'kye', 'mes', 'omar']

while len(names) < 2:
    name = input('Insert name: ')
    if name in usernames:
        names.append(name)
    else:
        print('Invalid user, try again')
```

The second example you make a loop that is aways verifying if the list of names has at least two names if it does the loops breaks and the code continues. Then to access each name you use `names[0]` and `names[1]`.

---

As commented by Patrick, you should try reading about [loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).